# Canvas stretching when using column-count

Tags: html, css, angular, chart.js

I am using chart.js and I have two pie charts and a bar chart which I would like to display in a single row.  I want the bar chart to be larger than the individual pie charts, so I did the following.

To get the two pie charts to fit into a single column I used column-count.

Here is the CSS which I am using

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    align-self: stretch;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.container div {
    flex: 1;
}

canvas {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}


.pie {
    column-count: 2;
    max-height: 93%;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pie">
            <canvas baseChart [data]="pieFeeChartData" [type]="pieChartType"
                [options]="pieFeeChartOptions">
            </canvas>
            <canvas baseChart [data]="pieFooChartData" [type]="pieChartType"
                [options]="pieFooChartOptions">
            </canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <canvas baseChart [data]="barBlahChartData"
                [options]="barBlahChartOptions" [type]="barChartType">
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My best solution is to set `max-height` in `.pie` to 93%.  It does give me close to what I want, but it is not exact and the formatting is inconsistent with smaller window sizes.  It is not bad, but I am hoping to find a more precise solution without using a hard coded value.  I have tried a lot of different flex settings, but I want to keep these CSS settings consistent throughout the project as much as possible, so that is not ideal either.

Here is a screenshot of what is happening when I DONT set `max-height: 93%;`

[image: No max-height setting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could greatly simplify this using grid.  It will give you more predictable results and it will be more reusable in your project and it will be a lot easier to reason about as your project grows.

Also, notice how the `canvas` height value uses `!important` to override the fixed values of the height of your chart that are applied as inline styles by Chart.js.

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  /* 
    A standard 12 column grid can be evenly 
    divided into quarters and thirds.
  */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.col-full {
  grid-column: span 12;
}

.col-half {
  grid-column: span 6;
}

.col-quarter {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

/* ✨ Magic ✨ */
canvas {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

And now the HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-quarter">
      <canvas id="pieChart1"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-quarter">
      <canvas id="pieChart2"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-half">
      <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result:
[image: Screenshot of resulting grid showing the pie chart consuming twice as much width as each barchart.]